# Frankenstein image swap JavaScript needs tidy and possible automation

Tags: javascript, image, automation, swap, preload

I'm using the following JavaScript. It works fine, but it's a mess pieced together from various sources.

- I have a series of images.
- Each has a small version (1.gif) and a hidden, preloaded, large version (_1.gif).
- Click the small version and the large version replaces it.
- Click again and it swaps back:

  ```
  var lastMove;
  lastMove = new Date();

  function preload(arr) {for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) (new Image()).src = arr[i];}

  var index = 0;

  var picsA = ["1.gif", "_1.gif"];
  preload(picsA); picNumberA = 0;
  function showNextPicA() {if (new Date() - lastMove < 200) return false; if (picNumberA == (picsA.length -1)) {picNumberA = 0;} else {picNumberA = picNumberA + 1;}document.getElementById('placeholderA').src = pics1[picNumberA];}

  var picsB = ["2.gif", "_2.gif"];
  preload(picsB); picNumberB = 0;
  function showNextPicB() {if (new Date() - lastMove < 200) return false; if (picNumberB == (picsB.length -1)) {picNumberB = 0;} else {picNumberB = picNumberB + 1;}document.getElementById('placeholderB').src = picsB[picNumberB];}
  ```
- etc. with each image on the page like this:

  ```
  <img src="1.gif" id="placeholderA" onclick="return showNextPicA();"/>
  ```

So, first: is this mess dangerous or unecessary or is it fine?

And second: is there a way to *automate* so any image file will swap to a version with a standard prefix (say _) when clicked, then back again when clicked again?

Phew. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use sth like jQuery, in the onClick for each image, put

```
showNextPic($(this))
```

Then

```
var prefix = "_";
showNextPic(imgelement) {
    var src = imgelement.attr('src');
    if(src.indexOf(prefix) == -1) {
         src = prefix + src;
    }
    else {
         // remove prefix from src
    }
    imgelement.attr('src', src);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks cleaner! But I can't get it running... I have this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
var prefix = "_";
showNextPic(imgelement) {
    var src = imgelement.attr('src');
    if(src.indexOf(prefix) == -1) {
         src = prefix + src;
    }
    else {
         // remove prefix from src
    }
    imgelement.attr('src', src);
}
</script>` then this: `<img src="1.gif" onclick="showNextPic($(this))"/>` and there's no response. Is there also a way to slip preloading in there?

Comment: are you sure jquery is loaded? check firebug etc. for errors. check the src of the image after clicking once, see if it's changed. etc.

Comment: I _think_ jQuery's loaded - Chrome is telling me **Uncaught ReferenceError: imgelement is not defined** - could that be an issue? Sorry, I'm really clueless (if you can't already tell)!

Comment: instead of
    showNextPic(imgelement)

you need to put
    function showNextPic(imgelement)

Comment: Hey, thanks! That swaps the image on the first click, but it doesn't change back to the non-prefixed version on the second click... `var prefix = "_";
function showNextPic(imgelement)
{
    var src = imgelement.attr('src');
    if(src.indexOf(prefix) == -1) {
         src = prefix + src;
    }
    else {
         // remove prefix from src
    }
    imgelement.attr('src', src);
}`

Comment: of course it doesn't:
// remove prefix from src
is just a comment I made. you still need to implement that.

Comment: Ahhhh! Sorry, I really don't know what I'm doing, thanks for being patient, I'm sorry to drag this out... Could you show me how to implement it? Sorry, no worries if that's too much, thanks for taking me this far.